# Clase Clip al reproducir un .wav no reproduce sonido

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Al reproducir un archivo .wav, los sonidos no se reproducen, pero en netbeans si:

Este es mi código:

```
public Clip clip;

public void ponerMusica(String musica) {
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Sonidos/" + musica + ".wav")));
        clip.start();
    } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor comparte una captura de la ventana de Projecto y abre el zip generado para ver si están los archivos de sonido dentro del jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es un problema conocido que es relacionado a la propiedad reposicionable del `InputStream`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591852/how-to-cast-from-inputstream-to-audioinputstream

en este caso si tu `InputStream` no tiene esta propiedad no es recomendable usar el método **[getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)**

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Sonidos/" + musica + ".wav")));
```

Si tu `InputStream` no es reposicionable puedes usar un workaround y este usar **[getResource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)** :

```
 clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/Sonidos/" + musica + ".wav")));
```